# python pandas iloc works on jupyter but not on flask

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I am developing an API from flask and for that I had to use pandas in between of a function. So to access a data I used pandas iloc but it shows an error 'IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds'.

Here's my code:

```
price = float(cf.loc[cf['company_name'] == 'Agricultural Development Bank Limited', 'Close'].iloc[0])
return price
```

If I run the same thing at jupyter then it works perfectly.

[Cjeck out the screenshot of running this code in jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/650sP.png)

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably trying to index an empty dataframe. For illustration try running this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df.iloc[0]
```